# Graphs' implementation in c++

Tags: c++

Given adjacency relation like

> 3 -> 4
>   1-> 3
>   Etc..

How do I construct a graph of it. I want a easier implementation which can be understood by a beginner. I know about self referential structures. Please help

Comment: If you haven't done it yet, then please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do you ask us to write code for you? If you use google you will immediately find some implementations, like [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77544/graph-implementation-adjacency-list-2-0) one.

Comment: @Nikita as I said I do not understand such technical implementations :)

Comment: @AkshatBhargava I see, but you should do some effort by yourself to understand the topic and after that ask more specific question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use **[Adjacency Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix)**, it's pretty simple and easy.

Adjacency matrices are matrices which define relations between the vertices of a graph.

[image]

See in the example above, you have an edge going from vertex `1` to `2`, so there is a `1` at the index `[1][2]` of adjacency matrix, similar is the case with `[1][3]` and so on.

And you don't have any edge going from `1` to `5`, so there is a `0` at index `[1][5]`, and so on.

You can also use **[Adjacency List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list)**, now go ahead and google it to have some understanding of how to use Adjacency Matrices and Adjacency Lists, and come back with some real problem then.

**EDIT**

I see, you don't have any understanding of how to implement a graph, let me write some examples for you using **Adjacency Matrix**.

I'm assuming that you know how to allocate a 2D array in c++.

Now, if you want to create an adjacency matrix for a graph containing `n` vertices, simply create a 2D array of size `n x n` and initialize all of the elements in it with `0`.

```
int** createAdjacencyMatrix(int n){
    int** graph = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        graph[i] = new int[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            graph[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    return graph;
}
```

There you go, call this function, and you've created yourself an Adjacency Matrix.

```
int** graph = createAdjacencyMatrix(5);
```

Now, you can do whatever you want to do with your graph (For now, it doesn't have any edges).

To have edges in it, simply place `1` wherever you want to put an edge.

```
void putEdge(int** graph, int startFrom, int endAt, int totalVertices){
    if (startFrom >= 1 && startFrom <= totalVertices && endAt >= 1 && endAt <= totalVertices){
        graph[startFrom - 1][endAt - 1] = 1; // Because c++ uses 0 based indexing, so 1 will be stored at 0, 2 at 1 and so on.
    }
}
```

Now, simply call this function, and add some edges to your graph.
So i'm gonna put some edges and create the above shown graph in it.

```
putEdge(graph, 1, 2, 5);
putEdge(graph, 1, 3, 5);
putEdge(graph, 1, 4, 5);
putEdge(graph, 2, 3, 5);
putEdge(graph, 3, 2, 5);
putEdge(graph, 5, 2, 5);
putEdge(graph, 4, 4, 5);
```

Now, you can do whatever you want with your graph, like should we calculate how many outgoing edges `vertex 1` has?

For this, you can simply loop through the row 1

```
int noOfOutgoingEdges(int** graph, int vetex, int totalVertices){
    if (vertex < 1 || vertex > totalVertices)
        return -1;

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < totalVertices; i++){
        if (graph[vertex - 1][i] == 1)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

At the end, you should de-allocate the allocated memory for adjacency graph.

```
void deallocateGraph(int** graph, int totalVertices){
    for (int i = 0; i < totalVertices; i++)
        delete[] graph[i];
    delete[] graph;
}
```

So, i think by now, you'd have much better understanding.

I've implemented the graph with using just the functions, and passing adjacency matrix to them (my bad), I strongly recommend to implement the Graph in a class, which handles all of the Graph stuff itself, and you don't have to pass adjacency matrix to it, you shouldn't even have to know whether the Graph class is implemented using Adjacency Matrix or some other method (of course when using the class, not implementing it)

You class should be like this:

```
class Graph{

   int** adjMatrix;
   int totalVertices;

public:
   Graph(int totalVertices);
   void putEdge(int startFrom, int endAt);
   int noOfOutgoingEdges(int vertex);
   int noOfIncomingEdges(int vertex);
   ~Graph(); 

};
```

Now, go ahead and implement this class and add whatever functions you want in there.

Comment: @akshat-bhargava have a look at the examples now, and tell me whether they help you or not.

Comment: Thank you so much, I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Use proper abstraction level.  You want to represent each node as an int with a set of neightbours ?

```
map<int, set<int>> neighbours  {
    { 1, { 2, 3, 4} },
    { 2, { 3 }},
    { 3, { 2 }},
    { 4, { 4 }},
    { 5, { 2 }}
};
```